# Two Definitions of the Weyl Tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors, curvature

I'm reading "Textbook in Tensor Calculus and Differential Geometry" by Prasun Kumar Nayak and came across the Weyl tensor/projective curvature tensor $C_{kijl}$. The book states that
$$C_{kijl}=R_{kijl}+\frac{1}{1-N}(g_{kj}R_{il}-g_{kl}R_{ij}) \tag{1}$$

However I found on Wikipedia that
$$C_{iklm}=R_{iklm}+\frac{1}{N-2}(R_{im}g_{kl}-R_{il}g_{km}+R_{kl}g_{im}-R_{km}g_{il})+\frac{1}{(N-1)(N-2)}R(g_{il}g_{km}-g_{im}g_{kl})  \tag{2}$$

It was not immediately obvious to me that both of these are equivalent to each other?

Comment: Is there a typo in your first formula? It seems obviously wrong unless there is some strange assumption about the metric. (Consider what it claims to tell you about flat space, for example...)

Comment: The correct one is : $C_{kijl}=R_{kijl}+\frac{1}{1-N}(g_{kj}R_{il}-g_{kl}R_{ij})$. There is [a typo in formula in the book.](https://books.google.com/books?id=IQWLMHc0FaIC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA239#v=onepage&q=%20Weyl%20tensor&f=false)

Comment: @Anthony Carapetis Yes you're right I mistyped $R_{ij}$ as $g_{ij}$. (corrected in edits). Is the second definition more complete though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first equation $C_{kijl}=R_{kijl}+\frac{1}{1-N}(g_{kj}R_{il}-g_{kl}R_{ij})$ is not the usual Weyl tensor. It is **Weyl projective curvature tensor** and it is different from Weyl tensor. It usually denoted by $W_2$. [See definition 2.1 here](http://repository.ias.ac.in/31209/1/31209.pdf).

In the NAYAK's book you should read "projective curvature tensor or Weyl tensor" as "**projective curvature tensor** or **projective Weyl tensor**".